# ImportError: No module named visual

Tags: python, 3d, importerror, vpython

I am trying to run [this](http://vpython.org/contents/contributed/chessboard.py) Python Program on Ubuntu but I am getting an error that says

```
ImportError: No module named visual
```

Can you guys please guide me on how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: have you run `sudo apt-get install python-visual` to install Visual Python?

Comment: its start working thank you.... but very slow

Answer (score 16):

`visual` module has been renamed to `vpython` lately.

So to run this now, you first install `vpython` like:

```
sudo pip3 install vpython
```

then replace the line:

```
from visual import *
```

with

```
from vpython import *
```

That worked for me.

Comment: vpython requires Python 3.5 or later. Is there a way to get a version of the visual module that is backwards compatible with Python 2?

Comment: @TheHagen  - older versions of vpython are available here http://vpython.org/contents/download/

Answer (score 5):

The script requires Vpython to be installed.

Then, make sure it is actually installed. Alternatively, move the library into your local folder. If it still doesn't work, check for an `__init__` file.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a Python27 compatible version of vpython [here (direct link)](http://vpython.org/contents/download/VPython-Win-Py2.7-5.74.exe).

To use vpython, you should run your code through VIDLE which should've also been installed. Through VIDLE, the syntax "visual" should be accepted. This worked for me.

Comment: That link is for a specific version and for windows only. see above for the http://vpython.org/contents/download/ link that does not have this restriction.