# Python: No module named visual

Tags: python, visual-studio, vpython

I am obtaining the following error message when I try to run my code in Visual Studio Code: "No module named 'visual'"
I believe I do not have the package downloaded, would anybody be able to help in downloading the package visual in VS code? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592211/importerror-no-module-named-visual)

Answer (score 0):

See vpython.org for instructions on installing the vpython module.