# modulenotfounderror no module named 'visual'?

Tags: vpython

I am trying to convert a py file from VPython 2.7 Program to exe file (in windows) but I am getting an error that says.

ModulNotFoundError: No module named 'visual'
Can you guys please guide me on how can I resolve this issue?

I want my Python visual file to be able to receive input and give 3D output when it' converted to EXE mode.

For example; I want to create an exe file from this codes that are in py to create my 3D output as an exe file.

```
from visual import*
from time import*
from math import*
L1=0.1
H1=2.8
W1=4.0
W1=0.1
W2=0.0
T1=.15
L1 = 6
a1=-H1/2
b1=H1/2
c1=L1/2
d1=-L1/2
e1=W1/2
floor=box(pos=vector(0,a1,0),color=color.white,length=L1,height=T1,width=W1+T1)
right=box(pos=vector(c1,0,0),color=color.orange,length=T1,height=H1,width=W1)
left=box(pos=vector(d1,0,0),color=color.white,length=T1,height=H1,width=W1)
behind=box(pos=vector(0,0,e1),color=color.white,length=L1+T1,height=H1,width=T1)
front=box(pos=vector(0,0,f1),color=color.white,length=L1+T1,height=H1,width=T1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named visual](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592211/importerror-no-module-named-visual)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I sent codes for understsnding better.

Comment: You can get better help in the VPython:
 forum https://groups.google.com/g/vpython-users

Comment: "visual" is now "vpython"; see vpython.org for installation instructions.